# Datatables show loading... in tbody instead showing data

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I am using datatables to get data from json but when the page is ready tbody show loading... instead showing data from json response

here is my json

```
{"response":{"data":[{"id":"64D3AFAFA8DE403A92DD836AC12ED903","organization":"3F8B3208255142DCB1D5C7AE542847B0","createdBy":"534F676339874A288518CD9D19086219","description":null,"documentNo":"PR.64","businessPartner":"DE1D64A7DED34BE3BBD1EA8BBA6540A1","documentStatus":"oez_waitingcomplete","recordTime":1634267761609}],"status":0}}
```

my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "myurl",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        "column": [
            {'data': 'documentNo'},
            {'data': 'organization'},
            {'data': 'createdBy'},
            {'data': 'documentStatus'},
            {'data': 'description'},
            {'data': 'id'}
        ]
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you must simply change your `dataSrc` to `"response.data"`.
The `data` array is inside the `response` object in your json response so this should do the trick.